GraphQL request in Angular 18 have no results with no errors
I have created this GraphQL module in Angular 18:
import { HttpClientModule, provideHttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ApolloClientOptions, ApolloLink, InMemoryCache } from '@apollo/client/core'
import { setContext } from '@apollo/client/link/context';
import { onError } from '@apollo/client/link/error';
import { ApolloModule, APOLLO_NAMED_OPTIONS, APOLLO_OPTIONS } from 'apollo-angular';
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-angular/http';
const uri = 'https://path/to/api/graphql';
export function createApollo(httpLink: HttpLink) {
    return {
      link: httpLink.create({ uri }),
      cache: new InMemoryCache(),
      defaultOptions: {
        watchQuery: {
          fetchPolicy: 'no-cache',
          errorPolicy: 'ignore',
        },
        query: {
          fetchPolicy: 'no-cache',
          errorPolicy: 'all',
        },
      }
    };
  }
  
  @NgModule({
    exports: [ApolloModule],
    providers: [
        provideHttpClient(),
      {
        provide: APOLLO_OPTIONS,
        useFactory: createApollo,
        deps: [HttpLink],
      },
    ],
  })
  export class GraphQLModule { }

And added it to the AppComponent component like this:
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import { Apollo, ApolloModule } from 'apollo-angular';
import { GraphQLModule } from './graphql.module';
import { GET_LATEST_BRANDS } from './get-all-brands';
import { pluck } from 'rxjs';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterOutlet, GraphQLModule],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.scss'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  brands!: any;
  title = 'ui';

  constructor(private readonly apollo: Apollo) {}
  ngOnInit() {    
    this.brands = this.apollo
      .query({
        query: GET_LATEST_BRANDS,
        variables: {first : 10, skip: 0}
      }).pipe(pluck("data"));
     
  }
}

The problem is the apollo neither gives any error nor returns any data. Even there is no network call. Did I miss any step in configuration?

this.apollo.query(... returns an Observable - you need to either subscribe to it and assign the results to brands or you need to use https://v17.angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe to bind to brands in the template.
